# Why Lollypop Music Player doesn't show any suggestions and don't connect with youtube-dl?

Tags: music, 20.10, youtube

Sorry for my bad english.

I was used to using the Lollypop Music Player in Ubuntu 20.04, and everything seemed to work fine. I also used the Suggestions feature frequently, to discover new music. However, after upgrading for Ubuntu 20.10, the app simply no longer shows the suggestions and doesn't connect to the web. When i turn on the option to connect with youtube-dl in the settings and close the window, the option automatically turns off. I also tried to open Lollypop with the terminal to see if there were any errors in there, but it shows nothing.

What can i do? :(

Comment: Are you the owner of ~/.local/share/lollypop and all the files in it, or is it `root` or something else?

Comment: yeah, i'm the owner.